Bypass windows and transfer images form hard drive to disk
I have an old work computer that I cannot log in to because I do not know the password. The computer has Windows 10 installed. I was wondering if there is any way to transfer data from my hard drive to another disk or computer without logging in to my Windows user account.

Wrong site to ask this one. Try superuser.com

The solution to my problem was to create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu and serting the USB drive as the primary boot device.
Anorher solution i thougt of was to remove the disk and using an SATA-to-USB to connect thr disk to antoher computer.

Still off-topic for SO though, so please read [tour] and notice this is not the only StackExchange site.
